# ¿Como combinar celdas usando la libreria phpspreadsheet para generar excel?

Tags: php, phpspreadsheet

Tengo un código que realiza una consulta a la base de datos para generar una cabecera con los artículos y su descripción en la fila 1 también genera columnas pivot con los nombres de las líneas y los grupos esa consulta la puedo realizar agrupando los nombres de las líneas y grupos en la fila 1  el problema que estoy tendiendo es que me esta repitiendo los nombres de las líneas y grupos cuando debería imprimir una sola vez comparto mi código por si alguien pueda ayudarme.

```js
sc_include_library("sys", "phpspreadsheet", "vendor/autoload.php", "include_once = true", "Require = true");

$documento = new\ PhpOffice\ PhpSpreadsheet\ Spreadsheet();

$documento

  -> getProperties()

  -> setCreator("Php")

  -> setLastModifiedBy('name')

  -> setTitle('Mi primer documento creado con PhpSpreadSheet')

  -> setSubject('Listado de Existencias a Fecha')

  -> setDescription('Este documento fue generado para Verificar')

  -> setKeywords('etiquetas o palabras clave separadas por espacios')

  -> setCategory('Lineas');

$nombreDelDocumento = "Listado_de_lineas.xlsx";

header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');

header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$nombreDelDocumento.
  '"');

header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');


$hojaDeProductos = $documento - > getActiveSheet();

$hojaDeProductos - > setTitle("Productos");

$encabezado = ["Articulo", "Descripcion_Articulo"];

$hojaDeProductos - > fromArray($encabezado, null, "A1");

$consulta = "SELECT Articulo, 

Descripcion_Articulo, Descripcion_linea, Descripcion_Grupo, Descripcion_sub FROM

Temporal_stock_Inventario ";

sc_select(ds, $consulta);


$productos = {
  ds
};

$colgrupo = 11;

$colinea = 11;

$numeroDeFila = 2;

foreach($productos as $producto) {

  $nomlinea = $producto['Descripcion_linea'];

  $nomGrupo = $producto['Descripcion_Grupo'];

  $nomsubGrupo = $producto['Descripcion_sub'];

  if ($band == 0) {

    $nomlineaActual = $nomlinea;

    $nomGrupoActual = $nomGrupo;

    $nomsubGrupoActual = $nomsubGrupo;

    $band = 1;

    if ($subGrupoActual !== $subGrupo) {

      $nomlineaActual = $nomlinea;

      $nomGrupoActual = $nomGrupo;

      $grupos = array();

      $lineas = array();

      $lineas[] = $lineaActual;

      $grupos[] = $Grupo;

      if (!in_array($lineaActual, $lineas)) {

        $hojaDeProductos - > setCellValueByColumnAndRow($colinea, 1,

          $nomlineaActual);

        $colinea++;

        $lineas[] = $lineaActual;
      }

      if (!in_array($GrupoActual, $grupos)) {

        $hojaDeProductos - > setCellValueByColumnAndRow($colgrupo, 2,

          $nomGrupoActual);

        $colgrupo++;

        $grupos[] = $GrupoActual;

      }

    }

  }

}
```

El Excel que actualmente esta generando la consulta se ve así como se puede ver repite los nombres de las lineas y los grupos

[image]

La impresión que debería realizar la consulta debería verse de esta manera:

[image]

Comment: Alguien puede ayudarme por favor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El encabezado también lo haces mediante la consulta?, te recomendaría hacer ese encabezado donde combinas las celdas de forma manual, para combinar celdas se utiliza [mergeCells](https://spreadsheet-coding.com/phpspreadsheet/merge-cells-in-excel-files%5D), dentro del paréntesis especificas el rango de celdas que quieres combinar ejemplo:

```
//COMBINACION DE CELDAS

$hoja->mergeCells('A1:C1')->setCellValue('A1','ENCABEZADO');
```

En principio de indica la hoja que esta activa, después se indica la combinación de celdas y en que rango, por ultimo le asignas el valor de dicha celda combinada especificando el valor de la celda combinada, en este caso toma el valor de donde inicia la combinación A1.